# How to make div elements of a parent div horizontal

Tags: html, css

This may be very naive but I am struggling to make the div children of a parent div element horizontal

I am trying to make a header, here is my code

```css
.logoImg {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  float: left;
}

.logo {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}

.addressDropDown {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div className="logo">
    <img className="logoImg" src='https://via.placeholder.com/100x100' alt="" />
  </div>
  <div className="addressDropDown">
    <p>Dropdown</p>
  </div>
  <div className="searchBar">
    <input type="text" placeholder="What are you looking for?" />
  </div>
  <div className="languageSetting">
    <p>language</p>
  </div>
  <div className="singInBtn">
    <p>signIn</p>
  </div>
  <div className="cartBtn">
    <p>Cart</p>
  </div>
</header>

<body>
  Body of the page
</body>
```

I would really appreciate it if someone can point out my mistake or give me some hints

Thank you

Comment: use `header` instead of `.header` in your CSS, `<header>` is an HTML tag, not a class.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just a small typo in your CSS code. The selector should be `header` (this selects all header elements) and not `.header` (this selects all element with the class "header")

Answer (score -1):

Your mistake is, that you try to change the style of `.header`. However to access the `<header>` element you have to **remove the dot**:

```
header {
   ...
}
```